# How to pass value between jquery and c# code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I have written jQuery as

```
     <script>
       $.backstretch([
    "../img/bg/19.jpg",
    "../img/bg/18.jpg",
  ], {
      fade: 1000,
      duration: 7000
  });
</script>
```

I need to make these two dynamic

```
   "../img/bg/19.jpg",
   "../img/bg/18.jpg",
```

For making them dynamic, I have created a web method in cs file

```
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
   public static List<string> GetImages()
   {
    SliderContext contextSlider = new SliderContext();

    string PageName = "Login Page";
    IEnumerable<_14Muslims.Domain.Entity.Slider> pType = contextSlider.SliderFetchAllEnabled(PageName);
    List<string> Images = new List<string>();
    foreach (Slider slider in pType)
    {
        Images.Add(slider.SliderImage.ToString());
    }

    return Images;
}
```

I am trying to tweak it in below lines of code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/Login/Login.aspx/GetImages',
      data: JSON.stringify({ Image: $.trim(Image) }),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function () {
      }
                  $.backstretch([
    "../img/bg/19.jpg",
    "../img/bg/18.jpg",
  ], {
      fade: 1000,
      duration: 7000
  });
  });
  </script>
```

I am not able to do it, Please help me in accomplishing this task.
Basically I want to fetch images dynamically from database in slide show.

The expected code should be something like

```
<script>
        $.backstretch([
         foreach(item in <object>)
          {
            item.Images
          }   
        ], {
      fade: 1000,
      duration: 7000
  });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Are you getting any error on console?

Comment: No error... I am not able to tweak the code

Comment: @user2179026 - Your method expects `prefixText` & `count` parameters but you are passing `Image`. Is your server side code even getting executed? I don't think so.

Comment: I have removed parameters and updated my question. I want to pass values(images) from getimages method and then pass it to slider code as mentioned in expected code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few modifications to your code should get it working.

The `GetImages()` web method expects no parameters so none should be passed in the AJAX call.

```
data: '{}',
```

The [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax) function on the AJAX call needs to have at least one parameter, representing the returned data from the web method.

```
success: function (data) {
    $.backstretch(data.d, {
        fade: 1000,
        duration: 7000
    });
}
```

**Result**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Login/Login.aspx/GetImages',
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.backstretch(data.d, {
            fade: 1000,
            duration: 7000
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What about fade and duration property in backstretch

Comment: Yep, missed those out. I updated the answer a few minutes back, if you're not seeing it then refresh the page.

Comment: Done. If it's still not working, check your browser console for any error messages.